# Rebuild IBM Portal embedded Derby database without a full reinstall

Tags: websphere, derby, websphere-portal

After exhausting all conceivable options over a matter of weeks, and after the drudgery of the back and forth with subpar IBM support, I have come to the conclusion that the only explanation for why my specific development environment fails to run a custom theme where other environments have no problems must have something to do with bad data in configurations contained in the embedded Derby database that comes packaged in the WebSphere Portal profile.

Google gives me no insights into the error I am running into, and I have confirmed the correctness of every single configuration file that even has the slightest chance of impacting the use of the Portal within a simple page.  Any and all types of caching or logs have been disabled and purged and tracing reveals no additional information that is helpful to diagnosing the problem.

Are there any scripts within the installation of Portal that can be run to wipe and rebuild the embedded database?  If not is the only option to scorch earth?  The schema and data are cryptic to me, but if it is possible to diagnose the database for specific problems are there any tools that can do that or do I need detailed architectural knowledge to have any hope of finding bad data in this software?

Comment: An embedded Derby database is storing its data in a folder on the filesystem. If you find and delete (or just rename, to start with) that folder, the database will be "gone". Dunno if your tool will deal with that by creating and populating a new database from scratch or not. You could also just connect to that database with the Derby "ij" tool (or Squirrel SQL, etc.) and have a look at the data in the database and issue "delete from" SQL statements to delete the data you don't want.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Thank you, I figured out how to connect to the database and navigate the schema and data.  The big problem really is that I don't understand if what I see is correct or not. IBM support has no idea so they ask questions of me about the IT infrastructure of my corp that I have no ability to answer, probably so they can just sweep me under the rug. Furthermore their online documentation can't seem to be crawled by Google well, so online searches never turn up anything noteworthy or interesting. I want to reinstall everything but if this happens in production we will have no idea.

Comment: Sadly I know very little about the IBM Portal product so can't be much more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered what the problem is and it does indeed have nothing to do with a corrupt database, but in actuality is an inherent conflict with packaged WAR files having Subversion metadata information on the WAS Portal platform.

When running any WAR or EAR file in WAS or any WAS based product, make sure to exclude all Subversion metadata files and folders from the build.  It apparently brings WAS and Portal to its knees.